# Cannot delete directory

Tags: linux, rm

I am trying to delete a directory.

```
rm -rf bla

rm: cannot remove ‘bla’: Directory not empty
```

It looks empty. I have also tried `rmdir`.

The ownership and groups looks fine. In fact, the directory was created by a tool I just ran.

```
drwxrwsr-x 2 me mygroup 4096 Oct 20 17:59 bla
```

I have changed permissions to `chmod 777 bla`, but I still cannot delete it.

I am on a cluster and do not have sudo rights. The file itself is not in any special system location or anything.

Comment: Have you tried "ls -ar blah/*"?  You might have hidden files in the directory.

Comment: @Garnet, itym `ls -a bla/`, without the final asterisk, since it won't match dotfiles

Comment: Yes. Still empty.

Comment: I would have ran `find bla -ls`. I doubt it, but is there a file system which will deny deleting a directory until all deleted files/directories are unlinked?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506319/why-am-i-getting-directory-not-empty-with-rm-rf).

Comment: Is `bla` a directory on an NFS filesystem? If so - and only if so - please take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/348315/100397 (the error message won't apply, but the symptoms and solution might)

Comment: *In fact, the directory was created by a tool I just ran.*
Please, provide the name of tool, version, ...

Comment: @roaima I have experienced this issue with .nfs0000093883 like temporary file which prevents the directory from being deleted. In this case, the directory is empty.

Comment: @Damir Not really sure if the tool matters. It is a bioinformatic tool called [CellRanger](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/what-is-cell-ranger). It itself is probably a mashup of various other tools.

Comment: I wrote to the system admin and it turns out the issue was beyond me.  Got this response:

"There is an issue with metadata on Glusterfs that causes this kind of behavior. I can fix this for you."

So, I don't know what kind of magic they do. Anyway, Thank you all for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `chmod 0777 bla` or `chmod g-s bla`. I think `s` bit in group permissions blocking the rm.

I think you must remove that bit. But I don't know how?
Also you can try remove all permissions with `chmod 0700 bla`

Comment: No, it shouldn't be the problem. To the part *But I don't know how?* -You gave the answer in your first sentence in this part `chmod g-s bla` - this is the exact way how to remove 'setgid' bit.

Comment: Changing the "s" didn't solve the issue.

Comment: The setgid bit on a directory will have no effect on a user's ability to delete it